# Clone remote site to local drive with SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013

I am a user (without Admin rights) of a remote SP site running SP 2013. My contact there wants me to clone the remote site to my local hard drive (where I have Admin rights).

SP Designer 2013 was suggested, which I have installed local. I am new to SP Designer and need a link/guidance.

Answer (score 1):

"Clone" is an inaccurate term as your local Hard drive does not support anything beyond basic file storage.  All metadata, security, history and so forth would be lost.  Your local machine also cannot support lists of any type.

However, that said, why not just use Explorer view and drag and drop the files from the SharePoint site to your local machine?

Comment: +1, if you want a true "clone" you should look at a site collection backup which you could restore later.

Comment: @dave, re your 2nd para, there are hundreds of files in dozens of directories. Re 1st para, by no lists, do you mean not even document titles in a directory/folder?

Comment: @kit, can a lowly user w/o admin rights do a site collection backup?

Comment: It should keep the document names, yes, but if you have defined titles different than the names, then yes, that would be lost as well unless those titles are defined in the Title field of the document itself (which is almost never done)